# jQuery nextUntil() - Apply to certain class only

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show all elements with a specific class using `nextUntil()`. Unfortunately it seems that I can only show ALL elements using next until.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/4qx4q/

```
$("ul#myList li").each(function(i, li) {
    $(li).nextUntil('.one').show('.two');
});
```

I would like to only show `.two` class.

Comment: `$(li).nextUntil('.one').filter('.two').show();`

Comment: Do you only want to show all the list element with the class two, or only those with class two, up until a certain point? Your question isn't clear to me.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks. If you put it as an answer i can mark it as correct.

Comment: Or, as the [DOC say](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) : `$(li).nextUntil('.one', '.two').show();`

Comment: `$('.two').show()` *I would like to only show `.two` class* [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qx4q/1/)

Comment: I did try that @Karl-AndréGagnon but it didn't work. I have now since tried it again and it seems to work. I must have has a javascript error. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think is simplier and you don't need `each()` loop:

```
$("ul li").nextUntil(".one",".two").show()
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qx4q/7/)